# PHP - Getting wrong result when selecting from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to get some results when selecting combo boxes.
here is my query:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM studentresult,student where studentresult.studentid=student.id and student.class='$classes' and term='$term'and studentresult.studentid=student.id and year='$year' ";
```

This query is returning all the studentresult.id = 2 where studentresult.id is primary.

This is the php code:

```
 <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["id"];?></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["studentid"];?></div></td>
    <td><?=$objResult["subjectid"];?></td>
    <td><?=$objResult["marks"];?></td>
    <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["term"];?></div></td>
    <td align="right"><?=$objResult["year"];?></td>
    <td align="right"><?=$objResult["rank"];?></td>
```

The id is taken from student table rather than being taken from studentresult table. Can someone help me with this.
**EDIT 1:

The id is present in both tables**


**EDIT 2:

Student result:

id| StudentID| SubjectID| Marks| Rank| Term| Year



Student:

id| Roll Num| class| Name| Surname**

Thanking You In Advance
Bhaamb

Comment: did id present in both table?

Comment: yes, it is present in both sir...

Comment: Then use like 'SELECT studentresult.id as stid' , and then use like <?=$objResult["stid"];?>

Comment: can you show your table structure.

Comment: Please, check your where condition you have compared the same condition two time i think issue is there ? Please change let me if you still face the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$strSQL = "SELECT *,studentresult.id as stid FROM studentresult,student where studentresult.studentid=student.id and student.class='$classes' and term='$term'and studentresult.studentid=student.id and year='$year' ";
```

Then

```
<div align="center"><?=$objResult["stid"];?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Better specify the column names instead of (*) from both the tables alias the column names to avoid column name conflicts if both are same and also try to use Join(Inner or Left) based on the need.

for example, some thing like this:

SELECT S.id AS student_id, SR.id as StudentResultId, S.class, s.year
FROM studentresult AS SR
INNER JOIN student AS S
WHERE SR.studentid=S.id and S.class='$classes' and s.term='$term'and SR.studentid=s.id and s.year='$year'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you use this twice in the where clause?

`studentresult.studentid=student.id`

Please define all needed columns explicitly while joining tables having the same column names, e.g.

`SELECT studentresult.id as sr_id, student.id as s_id ... FROM ...`

and change it in your php code:

`<?=$objResult["sr_id"];?>`